# How can I write a function That returns all the content of a text file using fgets in C programming?

Tags: c, file, text-files

I want to write a function char* lire(FILE* f) that it supposed to read a file of text and return its content, I want to return it and not just read it & display it.
I would like to use fgets.

**This code works but it's not what I want**

```
 char *lire(FILE *f)
{
    char *content;
    content = (char*)malloc((strlen(content) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    
   while (fgets(content,120000, f) )
   {
      printf("%s", content);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Instead, I tried this to **return** the text file but it just shows the first line of my text file**

```
char *lire(FILE *f)
{
    char *content;
    content = (char*)malloc((strlen(content) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    
   while (fgets(content,120000, f) )
   {
     return content;
   }
   
}
```

Comment: `fgets` read exactly one line of text. There is no way to read an entire file with `fgets` unless the file contains one single line of text. You probably need `fread`.

Comment: BTW: what do you think what `strlen(content)` is when `content` is a non initialized pointer?

Comment: I don't understand why it was possible to use it to read multiple lines in the first code while it's not in the second. Thank you.

Comment: There are multiple problems with both code snippets. Deal with my second comment first. It's quite important, believe me.

Comment: In your first code you print the line and just go for another round in your loop. That happens one line after the other. `fgets` does not read more than that single line. In the second code you just quit working and return after the first line.

Comment: when it's not initialized, maybe it returns a random value? I 'd like to know further explanation from you please.

Comment: _"when it's not initialized, maybe it returns a random value?"_: you're on the right track. Using an uninitialized variable triggers _undefined behaviour_ (google that term), that basically means that anything can happen: the program could crash, the program could behave eratically, the program could just appear to work fine, the program could appear to work fine and crash on the following day, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to read an entire text file into a single string using `fgets()`, but all of them will use `fgets()` iteratively.  You can try to determine the size of the file upfront and then allocate sufficient space and read into that space.  This works for disk files where you can seek on the file; it doesn't work if the input comes from a pipe, terminal, socket or most other things that are not disk files.  There's also a TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) problem; file sizes can change while your code is reading them.

Alternatively, you can simply read into allocated space, reallocating more space when it is needed.  This works with any type of input file.

Using `fgets()` means that the file cannot usefully contain null bytes.  That's because `fgets()` does not report how much data it read, so you have to use `strlen()` to find out how long the data was, and `strlen()` stops at the first null byte it encounters.

Using incremental allocation, you might end up with code like this:

```c
/* SO 7028-9928 */
/* Slurp a file using fgets() */

/* #include "slurp.h" */
/* SOF - slurp.h */
#include <stdio.h>

extern char *slurp_file(FILE *fp);
/* EOF - slurp.h */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_ALLOC 1024
#define MIN_SPACE   256
#define MAX_EXCESS  256

char *slurp_file(FILE *fp)
{
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t bufsiz  = INIT_ALLOC;
    char *buffer = malloc(bufsiz);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while (fgets(buffer + offset, bufsiz - offset, fp) != NULL)
    {
        /* Assumes data does not contain null bytes */
        /* Generic problem using fgets() */
        size_t newlen = strlen(buffer + offset);
        offset += newlen;
        if (bufsiz - offset < MIN_SPACE)
        {
            size_t new_size = bufsiz * 2;
            char  *new_data = realloc(buffer, new_size);
            if (new_data == NULL)
            {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            bufsiz = new_size;
            buffer = new_data;
        }
    }
    if (bufsiz - offset > MAX_EXCESS)
        buffer = realloc(buffer, offset + 1);
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *data;
    if ((data = slurp_file(stdin)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Size: %zu\n", strlen(data));
        printf("Data: [[%s]]\n", data);
        free(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When the program is run on its own source code, it produces output like:

```
Size: 1362
Data: [[/* SO 7028-9928 */
/* Slurp a file using fgets() */

…
    return 0;
}
]]
```

One alternative involves using `fread()` instead of `fgets()` — this can handle binary data, but you need to revise the function interface to report both the length of the data and the pointer to the start of the data.